# Need help adding text after an output in python

Tags: python

I want someone to input their weight in lbs which is then converted to kg. However the output is just the converted number. I can't figure out how to label the output with "kg". ex: 72 kg

```
weight_lbs = input('Weight (lbs): ')

weight_kg = int(weight_lbs) * 0.45

kg = 'kg'

print(weight_kg + kg)
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to do `str(weight_kg)` to make it a string type (instead of a number)

```
weight_lbs = input('Weight (lbs): ')

weight_kg = int(weight_lbs) * 0.45

kg = 'kg'

print(str(weight_kg) + kg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use %s and get rid of 'kg' = kg

```
print("%s %s" % (weight_kg,"kg"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version of the twice upvoted answer:

```
weight_lbs = input('Weight (lbs): ')

weight_kg = str(int(weight_lbs) * 0.45)

kg = 'kg'

print(weight_kg + kg)
```